# module not loading in the controller (undefined_method error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mixins

before applying the `BeforeOrAfter` module in my view, trying to get it to work in the console. getting the `NoMethodError: undefined method`before_or_after' for #` error:

```
> s = Artist.find(1)
> s.events.each do |event|
>     before_or_after(event.date)
> end
```

I chose to create a new modules subdirectory, app/modules/before_or_after.rb:

```
module BeforeOrAfter
  attr_reader :past
  attr_reader :future

  require "date"
  def initialize
    @datetime = DateTime.new
    @future = []
    @past = []
  end

  def before_or_after(datetime)
    if datetime < DateTime.now
      @past << datetime
    else
      @future << datetime
    end
  end
end
```

including it in application_controller.rb because all my controllers will be using it:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include BeforeOrAfter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run in your rails app, please add below line in config/application.rb,

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/modules')
```

To run in console, include your module first like,

```
include BeforeOrAfter
```

Comment: server won't start because config is undefined. should that line go into some kind of a block?

Comment: Yes, it must be inside the  class Application < Rails::Application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the rails environment is eager loaded before running the console. If you're in the console make sure you [require](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require) that file before using that method.

If you are running the full Rails app then your file should be auto loaded. You can read more about auto loading and the need for requires [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-and-initializers).

Comment: `require "before_or_after"` leads to LoadError, no such file. I know I'm doing it the less conventional way with creating modules/ subdirectory instead of sticking the module in to lib/ , could that be the problem? I'm running my dev server, restarted it many times.

Comment: The only time you can require modules just by the name like that is if the directory that contains the file is in the $LOAD_PATH array. You have to require the file using the relative path from the current working directory.

Comment: And you should also follow convention by placing that file under your lib directory.